# how make if statement emberjs with a true or false in a json file

Tags: json, ember.js

I want to make an if statement in my ember template that checks if a user is logged_in or not

the server returns the following:

`{"status":"ok","logged_in":false} or {"status":"ok","logged_in":true}`

if user logged in show the form else show content

how i check what's the "logged_in" status with? so i can use it in a ember template:

```
{{#if logged_in}}
show form
{{else}}
show content
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how you do it!  The problem you probably have is how to appropriately put it into context.  For simplicity, let's return it from the model hook, which will put it into the context of the related template.  In the case below, I've associated it with the `index` route, and we hit the index route/template when we hit just the root of our app.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return {"status":"ok","logged_in":false};
  }
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zohabeti/1/edit